# How to stop node inserting data into mongodb when I reload page

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I have a page with a form that allows you to insert information into a collection called "Farm". The function works, but if I ever reload the page the information gets submitted into the again. I created a filter function that avoids inserting the data if the req.body has a similar name and species property. But, I feel that there is a better way to go about doing this. Here is the code that creates the information  and pushes the data into mongodb

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var f = mongoose.model('Farm');    

module.exports create = function(req,res){
      var obj = req.body;
      console.log(obj)
      f.find({}, function(err,docs){
        var same = docs.some(function(element,index){
          return (element.name === obj.name && element.species === obj.species);
        })

        if(same === true){
          console.log('That name is already in the database');
          res.render('add',{msg:"Animal is already in the database"});
        }else{
          f.create({

            name: obj.name,
            species: obj.species.toLowerCase(),
            sex:obj.sex,
            weight: obj.weight,
            age: obj.age,


          }, function(err,info){
            if (err){

              throw err;
            }

              var message = 'Congratulations you have successfully added a '+info.species;
                res.render('add',{msg:message})



          })
        }
      })

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Typically the solution to this problem is to redirect the user to another page after inserting successfully (but not if there were errors, so the form can be edited and resubmitted).

```
res.redirect('/success')
```